# Looking for good book for Grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Before you close this as duplicate, I am aware of these 2 posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293389/best-books-to-learn-grails),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956656/groovy-and-grails-book))

but none of them links to a book that is for Grails 2.0 (all 1.2 or earlier)

I'm currently using [Getting started with grails, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0557183219) by infoQ,
but it referes to Grails 1.2 and I'm using 2.0, and there seems to be sound differences

Can you suggest a more recent book?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm with Don - just go for the documentation for now. Also, [questions asking for book recommendations are likely to get closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117990) (notice the two questions you linked to were both closed as well).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a version of Grails in Action covering 2.0 in the works. ( http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/10/31/springone2gx-2011-was-one-groovy-show.html ) - The MEAP should be announced in early 2012.

Comment: ...and, 2 years later, "Groovy in Action" is still in MEAP! :P

Comment: Re. comments above. The OP is asking about Grails books, not Groovy. "Grails in Action" second edition is MEAP, due for release in March 2014.

Answer (score 13):

There is no published book that covers Grails 2.0 (this version of the framework is less than a month old).

Luckily, the [official Grails reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) is excellent. I wouldn't waste your money on a book, when the reference is of such a high quality and is updated with every release.

Comment: The reference is indeed excellent, but at my current state of Grails knowledge, I need a lot more guidance than the reference has to offer.
But I'll revisit it and do the heavy-lifting using it once I get the basics straight

Comment: Any grails 1.x book will give you a goof start and will explain the basic principles behind grails. The reference will help you to make use of the new 2.0 features afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

you might like to look the new features

[Better Grails Productivity 2.0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHUPLOnUF4g)

Answer (score 1):

The Definitive Guide to Grails 2 http://www.apress.com/9781430243779

Programming Grails http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do

Both in early or alpha release